# Macports Port Select Commands

Tags: python, macports

What are the new commands & or equivalents of:

```
python_select -L (shows available python versions)

python_select -s (sets the default version of your choice of python).
```

I know they have changed to `--list`, `--set`, `--show` but there doesn't seem to be an example of how to properly use each one. For example, if I use `port select --set` I get the following:

> Error: port select [--list |--set |--show]  [].

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To list:

```
port select --list python
```

To show:

```
port select --show python
```

To select:

```
sudo port select --set python <the python version>
```

Comment: Any link to the `port select` documentation?

Comment: Also there is `port select --summary` for everything installed.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Currently there is no online documentation; if you have MacPorts installed locally then you have `port help select`.

Comment: @FranklinYu: And **that** is actually the answer here!