# python installation can't find psycopg2 ImportError

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, macports, psycopg2

I'm calling on psycopg2 with

```
import psycopg2
```

I get the std error

> ImportError: No module named psycopg2

I installed my copy with macports, so I'm curious why it wouldn't work because all of the dependencies should be downloaded as well.
I don't have any experience with Postgresql, nor this module, so I don't know what could be going wrong.  Fact is, another project I'm trying to get built calls upon it, so if I could avoid using this I would.  :)

I'm sure that postgresql is installed, but that has little to do with the fact that my installation can't find psycopg2.  Any suggestinos would be appreciated.

```
$ which python
```

reveals

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
```

and

```
$ python --version
```

reveals

```
Python 2.7.3 -- EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)
```

I don't necessarily want the version of EPD_free, but I had to install it for (somewhat) unrelated reasons.

Comment: is there a `/opt/local/bin/python`?

Comment: only `/opt/local/bin/python2`, and `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacPorts installs its own version of Python alongside Apple's version.  You can manage the active version of Python (the one that gets run when you type in `python` at the command line or by /usr/bin/env) by using the `port select` command.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612009/macports-port-select-commands).

Comment: thanks for your info.  do you have any idea of why this would lead to the import error?

Comment: It's because there are two versions of Python installed.  Macports installs psycopg under its copy so you wouldn't see it running Apple's copy.