# ImportError: No module named psycopg2 after MacPort install

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, macports, psycopg2

I am calling on psycopg2 with `import psycopg2` but receiving `ImportError: No module named psycopg2`.

I am working on a project that uses Psycopg for its database, which unfortunately, I have zero experience with. I've installed Psycopg using MacPort with `sudo port install py27-psycopg2`.

Essentially, my problem is exactly the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409944/python-installation-cant-find-psycopg2-importerror) **except** that the solution to that one does not work for me. I have tried the import command after switching between active python versions and still get the import error. I'm probably missing something dumb but any help would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you build your Python environment using `virtualenv` and install minimum number of packages using `port` or `sudo`. This way you have much better control to see what packages are installed and which ones fail. Official Python tutorial how to install packages: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#virtual-environments

Comment: You may have to open a new shell or type `hash -r` after changing the Python selection. Basically, you need to make sure that `type python` prints `/opt/local/bin/python`, or your change of active python was not picked up by your shell.