# Sklearn installation in OSX

Tags: python, macos, import, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have installed `sklearn` using the following commands (I tried both) but when I include it I receive the following error:

```
sudo port install py26-scikit-learn
or:
sudo port install py27-scikit-learn
```

The problem is:

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

You know what maybe wrong?

ANSWER: This worked for me:

```
sudo port select --set python python26
```

Comment: Have you compared `sys.path` and port installation path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct python binary. When you install scikits using macports, it becomes available in the macports version of python - not apple's. [Use the port select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612009/macports-port-select-commands) command to change which python is the default when you simply call "python"

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked for me after setting Python version to Python26.