# Problems setting up pySDL2 on mac os x 10.9

Tags: macos, sdl, osx-mavericks, pysdl2

I am having trouble setting up PySDL2 on my macbook pro running OSX 10.9. I downloaded and installed SDL 2.0.1 and I am trying to follow the PySDL2 tutorial here: http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html

I do not know what to do when it says "it is also possible to set the environment variable PYSDL2_DLL_PATH, which shall point to the directory of the SDL2 library." I tried running "export PYSDL2_DLL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks", but I don't know if that's what I'm supposed to do. Currently when I try to run this code:

```
import sys

try:
    import sdl2.ext as sdl2ext
except ImportError:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)

from sdl2.ext import Resources
RESOURCES = Resources(__file__, "resources")
```

I get the error "ImportError: No module named 'sdl2'"
So how do I properly set this up?

Edit: Using macports I got things setup correctly. Thank you sirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing it via [macports](http://macports.org)?

```
$ sudo port install py-SDL
```

Comment: I think I installed it correctly though. I just don't know how to set it up so I can use it.

Comment: I tried using macports anyway to see if that fixed my problem. I think it installed correctly (I ran sudo port install py-SDL2) and it seemed to work. However I still cannot import sdl2 in python. I must not have python "linked up" with the sdl2 library. How do I do this?

Comment: You'll need to use the python supplied with macports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612009/macports-port-select-commands

Comment: Ok now I'm getting somewhere! Except I still have errors trying to run that code. I'll edit my question and post the new errors.